# Is supremum over a compact domain of separately continuous function continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ be metric spaces, and consider the product metric space $(X\times Y,d)$ with a product metric $d$.

Let $f(x,y):X\times Y\to \mathbb{R}$ be a separately continuous function.

Suppose $X$: compact.

**Is $g(y)=\sup\limits_{x\in X}f(x,y)$ continuous?**

What if $Y$ is also compact?

---

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Suppose $X$ is not compact. Then, it fails even when $f$ is (jointly) continuous.
A counter example is given http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_analyst_2005&task=show_msg&msg=4110.0001. 
That $x$ can go as far as possible does bad.

Another counter example where $X$ is not compact is [Supremum of continuous functions is continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263763/supremum-of-continuous-functions-is-continuous).

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are compact, and $f$ is (jointly) continuous. Following the argument here:
[How prove this $g(x)=\sup{\{f(x,y)|0\le y\le 1\}}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609012/how-prove-this-gx-sup-fx-y0-le-y-le-1-is-continuous-on-0-1)
it seems to hold, using $f$ being uniformly continuous on $X\times Y$.

Go back to my question. In this case, we cannot use the uniform continuity. I tried doing the following and got stuck. From the compactness of $X$ and continuity in $x$, we can take $x^*_j\in\mathrm{argmax}_x f(x,y_j)$, ($j=1,2$), and
$$
|g(y_1)-g(y_2)|\le |f(x_1^*,y_1)-f(x_1^*,y_2)|+|f(x_1^*,y_2)-f(x_2^*,y_2)|.
$$
The first term is good as $f(x_1^*,\cdot)$ is continuous, but I could not do anything with the second term, and started to think maybe this is not true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a counterexample.

Take $f\colon [0,1]\times[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ defined by:
$$
f(x,y) = \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2},\quad f(0,0)=0.
$$
Notice that $2xy = x^2 + y^2 - (x-y)^2 \le x^2+y^2$ hence $f(x,y)\le 1$. While $f(y,y) = 1$.

Of course $f$ is separately continuous, but for $y>0$ one has:
$$
\sup_x f(x,y) = f(y,y) = 1
$$
while $f(x,0)=0$ hence $\sup_x f(x,0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general. As a counterexample, I will use the compact space $X = \overline {\Bbb {N}}=\Bbb {N}\cup \{\infty\} $, the one point compactification of $\Bbb{N} $.

If we have a sequence of functions $(f_n)_n $ defined on any metric space $Y $ (we will consider $Y=[0,1] $) with $f_n (y)\to 0$ for all $y\in Y $ and if each $f_n $ is continuous, then
$$
F : X\times Y \to \Bbb {R}, (n,y)\mapsto   \begin {cases} f_n (y),&y \in \Bbb {N}\\0,&y=\infty
\end {cases}
$$
is separately continuous. It suffices to find such a sequence, so that
$$
y\mapsto g (y):=\sup_{x \in X} F (x,y)=\sup_{n \in \Bbb {N}} f_n (y)
$$
Is not continuous.

To this end, let
$
f_n :[0,1]\to \Bbb {R}
$ be affinely linear on the intervals  $[0,1/n], [1/n,2/n] $ with $f_n (0)=0$, $f_n (1/n)=1$, $f_n (2/n)=0$ and $f_n (y)=0$ for $y \geq  2/n $ (draw a picture!).

Then all properties from above are satisfied, but we have $g (0)=0$, while $g (1/n)\geq 1$ for all $n $. Thus, $g $ is not continuous.